# Concatenate a retrieved range with line break (vbCrlf)?

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, summary

Started a new thread to adjust code I had written (with much help from @Doomenik as I am very new to VB thank you sir!)

Essentially, my code cycles through each worksheet that represents a customer and sends the data from specified cells/ranges to a "Summary" sheet.

It all works fine but what I can't seem to get it to do now is where a range is retrieved, to concatenate the values into one cell using a line break between each record.

Examples:

Customer Name: B9

Products A: H10:H34

Products B: H38:H49

Other Products: Q10:Q20

Online Access: R37

Where Products A / Products B / Other Products will have multiple values, how can I get these concatenated to the cell it copies to in the Summary sheet as opposed to across the row?

Example:

**Current State:** Product 1 (B1), Product 2 (C1), Product 3 (D1) etc (across row)

**Preferred State:**

(All in B1 with line break)

Product 1

Product 2

Product 3

Below is the code I have. I would really appreciate the help. This is a fantastic piece off code for anyone looking to do a Summary page and easily amended so please feel free to copy and use.

```
Sub Summary_All_Worksheets_With_Formulas()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Req As Worksheet
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim sumCell As Object
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim RwNum As Long
    Dim basebook As Workbook
        With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Add a worksheet with the name "Requirements Gathering"
    Set basebook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Req = Worksheets("Requirements Gathering")
    'The links to the first sheet will start column 2
    ColNum = 0

    For Each Sh In basebook.Worksheets
        If Sh.Name <> Req.Name And Sh.Visible Then
            RwNum = 13
            ColNum = ColNum + 2

            'Copy the sheet name in the A column

            Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Value = " "
                For Each myCell In Sh.Range("B9,H10:H34,H38:H49,Q10:Q20,R37")
                  If myCell.Value <> "" Then
                    RwNum = RwNum + 1
                    Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
                    "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
                    Req.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"

                    myCell.Copy

                    Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                  End If
                Next myCell
        End If

    Next Sh

    Req.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?  If it has `TEXTJOIN()`, you can do `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,B1:D1)` and turn Text Wrapping on for that cell.  In VBA if you're doing a string, you can loop through cells and do, say, `myStr = myStr & Chr(10) & cel.Value`

Comment: @BruceWayne thank you for the quick response, I am on 2013. I am very new to VBA so please bare with me.

I don't have TEXTJOIN() I did however try your suggestion to add Chr(10) to 'myCell' range and it sort of works but duplicates the values.

Comment: did you post the wrong code? i do not see anything that puts values indifferent columns

Comment: @jsotola I think you misread my problem. My data goes across a row. I want it to do that however when there is a range as opposed to a single cell, I want all data in that range to concatenate to one cell with a chr(10) between each value so for example, range H10:H34 is for Product A...If they had 4 products down column H, i.e. H10,H11,H12,H13 these values will go across to the summary page BUT I would like it so that all values in that range go to 1 cell, concatenated with line break.